# TypeError: anchor.BN is not a constructor

Tags: anchor, anchor-client

I am trying to write a simple Anchor program. It takes an input of u64 and creates an account by assigning that number to the single field of the account.

calling from test/index.js file:

```
const createAccount = async(num) => {
    await program.methods.createAccount(new anchor.BN(num))
    .accounts({
        account: programPair.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey 
    }).signer([programPair]).rpc();

    const account = await program.account.account.fetch(programPair.publicKey);
    console.log(account);}
```

However, running the test gives:

```
TypeError: anchor.BN is not a constructor
at createAccount (file:///C:/Users/amigo/Desktop/projects/pg/index.js:24:41)
```

Comment: Can you share a repro example on replit or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `anchor.BN` import is messed up somehow, because this looks ok to me at first glance, and the error indicates the instantiation of the `BN` is the issue.

You could:

- verify the import
- isolate the instantiation of the BN to avoid getting confused with other bits
- log `anchor.BN` itself, see if the output looks fishy

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with anchor import statement.

Comment: @CryptoSar please create a new answer with a more precise solution to the problem.  it will better help others in the future